# got trouble in template programming in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Header file as below:

```
#ifndef StrassenAlgorithms_Algorithm_h
#define StrassenAlgorithms_Algorithm_h

template<int size>
void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int A[size][size], int B[size][size], int C[size][size])

#include "Algorithm.cpp"
#endif
```

second is corresponding .cpp file:

```
template<int size>
void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int A[size][size], int B[size][size], int C[size][size]){
if (size == 1) {
    return;
}

const int n = size / 2;
int A11[n][n];
int A12[n][n];
int A21[n][n];
int A22[n] [n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        A11[i][j] = A[i][j];
        A12[i][j] = A[i + n][j];
        A21[i][j] = A[i][j + n];
        A22[i][j] = A[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

int B11[n][n], B12[n][n], B21[n][n], B22[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        B11[i][j] = A[i][j];
        B12[i][j] = A[i + n][j];
        B21[i][j] = A[i][j + n];
        B22[i][j] = A[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S1 = B12 - B22 */
int S1[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S1[i][j] = B[i + n][j] - B[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S2 = A11 + A12 */
int S2[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S2[i][j] = A[i][j] + A[i + n][j];
    }
}

/** S3 = A21 + A22 */
int S3[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S3[i][j] = A[i][j + n] + A[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S4 = B21 - B11 */
int S4[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S4[i][j] = B[i][j + n] - B[i][j];
    }
}

/** S5 = A11 + A22 */
int S5[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S5[i][j] = A[i][j] + A[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S6 = B11 + B22 */
int S6[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S6[i][j] = B[i][j] + B[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S7 = A12 - A22 */
int S7[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S7[i][j] = A[i + n][j] - A[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S8 = B21 + B22 */
int S8[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S8[i][j] = B[n][j + n] + B[i + n][j + n];
    }
}

/** S9 = A11 - A21 */
int S9[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S9[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][j + n];
    }
}

/** S10 = B11 + B12 */
int S10[n][n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        S10[i][j] = B[i][j] + B[i + n][j];
    }
}

int P1[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(A11, S1, P1);

int P2[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(S2, B22, P2);

int P3[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(S3, B11, P3);

int P4[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(A22, S4, P4);

int P5[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(S5, S6, P5);

int P6[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(S7, S8, P6);

int P7[n][n];
strassen_matrix_multiplication<n>(S9, S10, P7);

/** C11 = P5 + P4 - P2 + P6 **/
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        C[i][j] = P5[i][j] + P4[i][j] - P2[i][j] + P6[i][j];
    }
}

/** C12 = P1 + P2 **/
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        C[i + n][j] = P1[i][j] + P2[i][j];
    }
}

/** C21 = P3 + P4 **/
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        C[i][j + n] = P3[i][j] + P4[i][j];
    }
}

/** C22 = P5 + P1 - P3 - P7 **/
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        C[i + n][j + n] = P5[i][j] + P1[i][j] - P3[i][j] - P7[i][j];
    }
}

return;


}
```

last is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Algorithm.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
const int size = 2;
int A[size][size] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
int B[size][size] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
int C[size][size] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
strassen_matrix_multiplication<2>(A, B, C);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++) {
        cout << C[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

I got two compilation errors, one said in .cpp file

```
"Expected initializer before 'template'"
```

at the first line. I don't know what this means.
and the other said in main file that

```
"'strassen_matrix_multiplication' not declared in this scope"
```

how can I fix these errors? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your header file should usually not contain code, unless it is the code of `static inline` functions or of template functions. And you should compile with `g++ -Wall -g`. And intuitively, header files are "smaller" (since they should contain more declarations than definitions) than source files.

Comment: You are including the .cpp in your header. It needs to be the other way around.

Comment: @Svalorzen:I know what you mean.I used "inclusion model" which described in 《c++ primer》 to compile template function here.

Comment: Yes, including the .cpp is "ok" in this case. I'm sure it's something obvious, but can't spot it right now.

Comment: @Svalorzen: No, that is not correct. The OP is doing that to get the function template definition in the header. The use of `.cpp` is confusing, though.

Answer (score 3):

As  JasonD correctly said, you are missing `;` after function declaration in .h file. You do not need to put `;` after function definitions.   Yes, C/C++ is sometimes confusing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a `;` after a function definition has nothing to do with the function definition.

Comment: You are correct. Need to fix answer ...

Comment: Nah it's okay -- I'm just being picky. That my pickiness exists attached to the answer as a comment will suffice.

Comment: exactly. That error disappeared.But I got 7 compilation errors all saying that 'not matching function for call to 'strassen_matrix_multiplication(int [0u][0u], int [0u][0u], int [0u][0u])'', I know it means that I passed incorrect parameters to that reverse call.How should I modify it?

Comment: These are not your last errors.  Change signature to accept pointers. Your matrix parameters are decaying into pointers.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky:I have changed signature to accept pointers like this:                                                               void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int (*A)[size], int (*B)[size], int (*C)[size]), but it remains same.

Comment: I've answered the question.  You didn't accepted it.  You are asking new unrelated questions for which I even do not have source.  You can try post this as new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky:ok,I will put forward a new question.